# Obfuscator for Javascript and Script#

Tags: script#

Could you indicate a free obfuscator that works for Script# javascript generated code?

Comment: Obfuscation is not a practical strategy for JavaScript. You cannot "protect your code" in any non-trivial fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release scripts are somewhat "obfuscated" ... I am not sure if you're specifically into obfuscation or minimization.

The Ajax minimizer (see codeplex) or Google Closure compiler come to mind for minimization. You might try them, and see if they work for you.

Did you try them and they did not work? What issues did you run into?

As I look to the future, I'd like to change the focus of script# from producing minimized script to instead producing minimizable script and output script in a way such that it complements the google closure compiler. So hearing any issues you've run into will help understand what needs to be done.

Comment: Hi, I have an application that I would like to protect my code. The minification does a part of the job. But a more complete obfuscation would be better. I have not used Google Closure, Did you ever tried Jasob ??? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google Closure Compiler is not able to minify all code even with setting **ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS** because of string constants of type names.

I suppose to add following code for each type, field, method and enum value in order to obfuscate (in reality minify) your JavaScript code:

```
#if !DEBUG
    [ScriptName("u2")]
#endif
```